# Multibinding in RowDefinition Height

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to make converter for row height, that is dependent on 3 variables. Two of them are from view model and one is constant string. I made MultiValueConverter for this, but obviously its not setting the RowDefinition.Height value.

The code looks like this:

```
<RowDefinition Name="Row1">
    <RowDefinition.Height>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
            <Binding Path="PropertyFromViewModel1" />
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource DataGridName}" />
            <Binding Path="PropertyFromViewModel2" />
        </MultiBinding>
        </RowDefinition.Height>
    </RowDefinition>
```

Converter is working, it returns proper values (as strings).

Code for multivalue converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!((values[0]) is bool))
            throw new ArgumentException("First argument 'value' must be of type bool");
        if (values[1] == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Secound argument must be diffrent then null");
        if (!((values[2]) is bool))
            throw new ArgumentException("Third argument 'value' must be of type bool");

        var showParkedTransactionDataGrid = (bool)values[0];
        var datagridName = values[1].ToString();
        var isCustomerDiscountShowed = (bool)values[2];
        if (showParkedTransactionDataGrid)
        {
            if (datagridName == "ProductListDataGrid")
            {
                return isCustomerDiscountShowed ? "306" : "336";
            }
            else if (datagridName == "ParkedTransactionDataGrid")
            {
                return "*";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (datagridName == "ProductListDataGrid")
            {
                return "*";
            }
            else if (datagridName == "ParkedTransactionDataGrid")
            {
                return "0";
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I used before IValueConverter and it was working on RowDefinision Height property, but multibinding isnt.

Comment: Show us the MultiValueConverter too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Height is of type [System.Windows.GridLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx)

Make sure you return that from the converter.

**EDIT**

And, by the way, the converter is not very well designed! It is completely dependent on the naming of the controls. It will be very hard to find errors when renaming the controls.

You should consider another way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I also splited this for separete converters for diffrent controls so its not dependent on control name now.

Comment: You are welcome. My bet is that you do not need these converters at all. Just set the height to Auto and Bind the visibility of the controls to the viewmodel/data.

Comment: Unfortunatly not. Because we have specific designs, that if second of the datagrid is visible, then the first one have to have constant height, dependent also on another property.

Comment: OK, but I have to say that this feels very bad because of the fixed values in the converter. Perhaps you should make them parameters of the converter too. That would make it a more general converter and would allow a designer to specify the height.